# Ruby 1.8.7 is not installing through RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to install ruby  version 1.8.7 through Rvm, but can't installed this version and getting following error

```
Error running '__rvm_make -j4',
```

Comment: which OS you have?

Comment: i am using ubuntu 16.04

Comment: @NeerajAmoli Can you please add whole error log in question ?

Comment: Makefile:197: recipe for target 'ossl_rand.o' failed
make[1]: *** [ossl_rand.o] Error 1
Makefile:197: recipe for target 'ossl_bio.o' failed
make[1]: *** [ossl_bio.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/yasar/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p374/ext/openssl'
Makefile:293: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 1
+++ return 2

Comment: @NeerajAmoli add this log in your question, please update your question with full error log

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hk3XqwJ_wuzR9hUvAh3VnNr98yCwiOvR/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @NeerajAmoli- try `rvm pkg install openssl` and then  force install ruby `rvm reinstall 1.8.7 --force -C --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr`

Comment: @Sonalkumar sute  now this error comming Error running '__rvm_with ruby-1.8.7-head gemset_pristine' it saying you need to fix this gem manually . should i install it like this gem install pristine ?

Comment: What does running `rvm requirements` do?

Comment: @lloydpick it says, requirements installation successfull.